# Strange Chrome Network Behaviour

Tags: google-chrome

i am having troubles opening some urls in google-chrome (latest official version)
using chrome-canary the problem is gone.

can any one point me in the right direction:

TCP DUMP (non working sample, chrome - latest version)

[image]

TCP DUMP (chrome canary)

[image]

everthing with out-of-the box settings, already reinstalled chrome and removed all chrome settings folders.

also tried with `--disable-async-dns --disable-extensions`

firefox, safari, and even curl - work fine!

OS: osx

Answer (score 0):

ok seems to be a MTU related problem - changing mtu size fixed it, don't ask me why canary safari, curl and co. didn't have the problem